# Second SQL query not Inserting any value in database

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to insert question in question table and than getting that latest question `id`. I am trying to add options for it in other table named `select_op`. It inserts question successfully but not options. Even I am not getting any exception, method exits successfully.

```
int id=addQuestions(ques, survey_id); 

if(id>0){
    //not inserting anyvalue in database
    String sql = "insert into select_op("+ "first,"+ "second,"+ "third,"+ "four,"+ "question_id)"+" values(?,?,?,?,?)";     

    try {
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);
        PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1,option1);
        pst.setString(2,option2);
        pst.setString(3,option3);
        pst.setString(4,option4);
        pst.setInt(5,id);
        pst.addBatch();
        System.out.println(pst.executeBatch());
    }catch (BatchUpdateException e) {
        try {
            System.out.println(e);
            conn.rollback();
        } catch (Exception e2) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

```
//this function insert data successfully
public int addQuestions(String ques,String survey_id){

    String sql = "insert into question(question,survey_id) values(?,?)";        
    int id = 0;
    try {
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);
        PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        pstmt.setString(1,ques);
        pstmt.setString(2,survey_id);
        pstmt.addBatch();           
        pstmt.executeBatch();
        ResultSet keys = pstmt.getGeneratedKeys();  
        keys.next();  
        id = keys.getInt(1);  
        keys.close();  
        conn.commit();
        pstmt.close();
    }
    catch (BatchUpdateException e) {
        try {
            conn.rollback();
        } catch (Exception e2) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return id;
}
```

Any Suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Zaki Suggested 
Are you missing a commit ?

I did commit.. Solved :)
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`getGeneratedKeys()` may not be supported in mysql (I've never seen it used or tried it).

But I do know this works: Executing the query `select mysql_insert_id()` returns the last auto increment value - use that instead of `getGeneratedKeys()`.